# Method to evaluate v-if not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to get a method to return truthy falsely for a v-if statement. But right now the button always is true for some reason.

Here's my HTML(Pug):

```
button(v-if="!isAttending(report)" @click="qualify(report)") RSVP
```

And my JS (Vue)

```
methods: {
    isAttending (report) {
      var that = this
      var theReport = report
      if (that.$firebaseRefs.attending.child(that.user.user.displayName).child(theReport['.key']).child('going') === true) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
```

And my JSON Structure:

```
attending
 Me
   -KpWQkTrnWNjGrRMlXuM
     going: true
reports
 -KpWQkTrnWNjGrRMlXuM
   what: 'event name'
   participants
     -Me
       status: 'RVSPd'
```

Essentially what I am doing it asking firebase is something exists and returning true or false. I'm not convinced this is the best way but have yet to come up with better.

Comment: A method is fine. If anything in that firebase chain is async, though, that if will always return false.